# Multiple Counter Problem In For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Why is this not valid

```
for( int i = 0, int x = 0; some condition; ++i, ++x )
```

and this is

```
int i, x;
for( i = 0, x = 0; some condition; ++i, ++x )
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare variables of different types in the initialization of a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644707/can-i-declare-variables-of-different-types-in-the-initialization-of-a-for-loop)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: The alleged duplicate is newer than this question. Why would you close this?

Comment: @bitmask: The other question has a bit more explanation of what we're trying to do, and has more upvoted answers. But which to close is a judgement call.

Answer (score 43):

> when you need to declare two variables of different types, it can't be done by one declaration

Hackety hack hack:

```
for (struct {int i; char c;} loop = {0, 'a'}; loop.i < 26; ++loop.i, ++loop.c)
{
    std::cout << loop.c << '\n';
}
```

;-)

Comment: Wow! Never heard of this before.

Comment: That seems like a nice hack. Would you comment on some strange detail?
If I replace type of i variable with something like std::vector<int>::const_iterator, it won't compile...
It seems like dirty code anyway to write long temporary struct with two iterators in the for loop, but I just thirst for understanding.

Answer (score 41):

this works:

```
for( int i = 0, x = 0; some condition; ++i, ++x )
```

it's a variable declaration:

```
int i, j; // correct
int i, int j; // wrong, must not repeat type
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing spelling mistakes on my question

Answer (score 11):

Why should it be valid? It is a syntactically meaningless construst. What were you trying to say with it?

The first part of `for` header is a declaration. The

```
int i = 0, int x = 0
```

is not a valid declaration. It will not compile in `for` for the same reason why it won't compile anywhere else in the program

```
int i = 0, int x = 0; // Syntax error
```

When you need to declare two objects of type `int` in one declaration, you do it as follows

```
int i = 0, x = 0; // OK
```

The same thing can be used in `for`

```
for( int i = 0, x = 0; some condition; ++i, ++x )
```

(But when you need to declare two variables of *different* types, it can't be done by one declaration and, therefore, both cannot be declared in `for` at the same time. At least one of them will have to be declared before `for`.)

Answer (score 8):

Correct version is

```
for (int i = 0, x = 0; some condition; ++i, ++x)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is legal:

```
    for(int i = 0, x = 0; condition; ++i, ++x );
```

int x, int y is not a legal way of declaring variables;

Answer (score 3):

Because a variable declaration (like `int x`) is not an expression and the comma operator (`,`) only combines expressions.

Comment: This exposes a sad limitation of the for loop initialisation block. 
i.e. All variables initialised in the initialisation block must be the same type.

Comment: Beware, the `,` in the declaration `int x, y;` is NOT the comma operator!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this approach to calculate the diagonal difference. Here I am calculating the **sum of Antidiagonal**.

```
 for(int i=0,j=n-1; i<n,j>=0;i++,j--){
    sum_right += a[i][j];
  }
```