# Is for ({statements;}; condition; {statements;}) legal C?

Tags: c, for-loop, curly-braces

Bad style notwithstanding, is it legal C to have a for loop with braces inside the parens?  Like this:

```
char *a = "a ";
char *b = "b ";

for ( { int aComesFirst = 1;
        char *first = a;
        char *second = b;
      };
      aComesFirst >= 0;
      { aComesFirst--;
        swap(first, second);
      } )
{
  printf("%s%s\n", first, second);
}
```

If something along those lines is possible, am I supposed to put a semicolon after the first close braces, or would that add an empty statement?

I do realize that it is stylistically better to move the `char*` declarations outside the for loop and the `swap` to the end of the inside of the loop.  But style is not the point of this question, I just want to know if putting braces inside the parens is possible.

Comment: I take it that that horrific thing actually compiles?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.  That's just an example of the form of answer I am looking for.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348766/how-to-initialize-several-variables-in-a-for-loop-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've answered this before… this can easily be made legal in C or C++ by adding a local `struct` type. It's generally poor style, though.

```
char *a = "a ";
char *b = "b ";

for ( struct loopy {
        int aComesFirst;
        char *first;
        char *second;
      } l = { 1, a, b }; /* define, initialize structure object */

      l.aComesFirst >= 0; /* loop condition */

      l.aComesFirst--, /* loop advance */
      swap(l.first, l.second)
    )
{
  printf("%s%s\n", l.first, l.second);
}
```

Comment: `struct loopy` Ah! +1 love the tag; -1 Arrrggghhhh; result +0

Comment: ++ for hacking the loop into actually working; the only direct answer to my question.  And yeah, that's as stylish as bell bottoms.

Comment: There are probably compilers out there that will allow you to omit `loopy` and `l` to declare an anonymous object of anonymous type, so you can pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: The above compiles only if `swap()` is an expression (e.g., a non-void function, or macro whose expansion returns a value).

Comment: @JeffLearman The third part of `for` may be `void`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm not objecting to that; I'm objecting to the use of a void expression with the comma operator, which used to be illegal.  Evidently it's legal now, or at least gcc allows it.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not legal, but you can use commas to get half way there:

```
for (int a = 1, b = 2; a < 10; ++a, ++b)
```

You can't declare multiple variables of different types, and you can't use control structures in the last bit, but it's good enough most of the time.

If you didn't know, the comma used there is not some special syntax that can only be used in `for` loops, it's a general [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) that can be used anywhere to evaluate the left operand, followed by the right operand, and return the result of the right expression, i.e. `a, b == b`, and `a, b, c == c` and so on.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes if it's still the best.

Comment: ...and, frankly, the equivalent `while` structure will be clearer anyway. If you a determined to get limited scoping, just use a free standing `{}` block around the initialization-code-n-while-loop.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not legal.  If it was legal the code wouldn't work anyway because c has block level scope, so you wouldn't have access to an of the variables defined in the braces.

Answer (score 2):

That's not legal but this is:

```
for(i = 0, j = 10; i < 10; i++, j--)
{
  // ..
}
```

See: [the comma operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html)

Comment: ++ for the link to "the comma operator".  I didn't know that comma was a first-class and so useful operator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `gcc` with Statement Expressions? http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC63
Maybe that will make that type of code work. except it's `(int i = { stmts; }; { stmts; bool};  { ... })`

Comment: ++ Thanks for showing me the Statement Expressions extension.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard says (6.8.5.3/1)

> for ( clause-1 ; expr-2 ; expr-3 ) statement

I'm pretty sure neither `expr-2` or `expr-3` can be replaced by something not an expression (**a block is not an expression**), and I'm pretty sure `clause-1` also cannot be replaced by a statement.

Comment: +1 for the relevant citation and to counter whoever the downvoting idiot was.