# Why is it so 'hard' to write a for-loop in C++ with 2 loop variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ why can’t I write a for() loop like this: for( int i = 1, double i2 = 0; …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337126/in-c-why-cant-i-write-a-for-loop-like-this-for-int-i-1-double-i2-0)

A C developer would write this:

```
int myIndex;
for (myIndex=0;myIndex<10;++myIndex) ...
```

A C++ developer would write this to prevent the loop variable from leaking outside the loop:

```
for (int myIndex=0;myIndex<10;++myIndex) ...
```

However, if you have 2 loop variables, you cannot do this anymore.  The following doesn't compile:

```
for (int myIndex=0,MyElement *ptr=Pool->First;ptr;++myIndex,ptr=ptr->next) ...
```

The comma operator does not allow two variables to be defined this way, so we have to write it like this:

```
int myIndex;
MyElement *ptr;
for (myIndex=0,ptr=Pool->First;ptr;++myIndex,ptr=ptr->next) ...
```

Which defeats the advantage of having real loop-local variables.

A solution could be to put the whole construction between braces, like this:

```
{
int myIndex;
MyElement *ptr;
for (myIndex=0,ptr=Pool->First;ptr;++myIndex,ptr=ptr->next) ...
}
```

But this is hardly more elegant.

Isn't there a better way of doing this in C++ (or C++0x)?

Comment: Why would a C programmer necessarily put the variable above the loop?

Comment: @GMan Declaring it inside the for statement is only valid since C99, IIRC

Comment: @Wim: Which was 11 years ago. :)

Comment: As myIndex is not part of the conditional test I personally think it is bad style to put in inside the for(;;) it just makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just have to understand the first statement is a declaration (and that comma is *not* the comma operator). It's not any harder to do:

```
for (int i, double d; ...)
```

Than it is:

```
int i, double d;
```

Because `for (init cond; expr) statement` gets expanded to:

```
{
    init
    while (cond)
    {
        statement
        expr;
    }
}
```

A trick is to make that `init` statement a struct definition and instance, like:

```
for (struct { int myIndex; MyElement* ptr;} data = {0, Pool->First};
    data.ptr;
    ++data.myIndex, data.ptr = data.ptr->next)
    {
        // blah...
    }
```

Which becomes the same as:

```
{
    struct
    {
        int myIndex;
        MyElement* ptr;
    } data = {0, Pool->First};

    while (data.ptr)
    {
        {
            // blah...
        }
        ++data.myIndex, data.ptr = data.ptr->next;
    }
}
```

But I find that pretty ugly. In practice, I'd just split it up like you have. If scope is *really* a problem, which it probably isn't, throw the extra braces around there.

I don't think there's much to improve here without a bit of boilerplate code.

Comment: Oh that's an ugly solution, I'm kinda glad I didn't think of it.  :-)  I too much prefer putting the loop in its own block.

Comment: Answer accepted.  There doesn't seem a more elegant way than defining the variables outside the for-loop and putting the whole block between braces.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box! But yes, ugly! :-)

Comment: @Martin: Note that an `init` statement ends with `;`, so putting it into the equivalence is redundant/erroneous. (See §6.5.3.)

Comment: @GMan: Sorry.             :-)

Comment: @Martin: It's all good. :) Thanks for taking care of answers.

Comment: What about also adding an operator++ to your struct? :)

Comment: @miked: That's what I meant by boilerplate code. :) If I were to do that, I'd make it more generic...I wonder how generic it can be made.

Answer (score 8):

If I really wanted to confine the scope to the loop I would use:

```
#include <utility>
for (auto i = std::make_pair(0,Pool->First);
     i.second;
     ++i.first, i.second=i.second->next)
```

Comment: But now you loose all the information that was given by the variables names: `i.first` and `i.second` do not convey any information about the purpose of the variables, whereas `myIndex` and `ptr` give some (not a lot, but some).

Comment: Yes, there is a tradeoff to make here - I would say it is the standard tradeoff when using pair. If the purpose of the pair members is evident I would stick to pair. If not I would switch to a solution with explicit names.

Comment: @LucTouraille: you can always define a small struct for this in place of std::pair<>..

Answer (score 2):

At least C++ allows us to declare variables in the **if** clause, which which is sometimes used to declare a variable that only is only visible when some condition is true:

```
if (MyElement *ptr=Pool->First) // block is only entered when ptr!=0
{
 for (int myIndex=0;ptr;++myIndex,ptr=ptr->next)
 {
 }
}
// ptr is out of scope now.
```

This could be a method to limit the scope of ptr and index, while maintaining readability.

Comment: There is really no need for the if statement.  You can add braces (almost) anywhere you like to set up a new scope.

Comment: The `if() for() ...` pattern works also well with macros.