# Error in iterator declaration in a for loop

Tags: c++

```
void catchlabel()
{
    if(vecs.empty())
        return;
    else
    {
    cout << "The Sizeof the Vector is: " << vecs.size() << endl; 
    cout << "Currently Stored Labels: " << endl;
    /* Error 1 */
for ( int i = 1, vector<string>::iterator it = vecs.begin(); it != vecs.end(); ++it , i++) 
             cout << i << ". "<< *it << endl;
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I get the following error for:

1> error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'it'

How to fix this?

Comment: @Downvoter: Why are the answers all -1'd? They're all correct.

Comment: Duplicate-sh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440066/why-is-it-so-hard-to-write-a-for-loop-in-c-with-2-loop-variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare variables of different types in the initialization of a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644707/can-i-declare-variables-of-different-types-in-the-initialization-of-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't declare items of multiple types in the initial statement of a `for` loop, just like you can't say `int i = 1, vector<string>::iterator it = vecs.begin();` as a standalone statement. You'll have to declare one of them outside the loop.

Since the C language you have never been able to declare multiple variables of different types in one statement (although pointers are a rather odd exception):

```
int i, double d;  /* Invalid */

int i, j; /* Valid */
```

This behavior is inherited by C++, and applies to each statement within a `for` loop as well as standalone statements.

Comment: @night: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440066/why-is-it-so-hard-to-write-a-for-loop-in-c-with-2-loop-variables).

Comment: @GMan: I'm sorry, that wasn't useful. That just explains that it's not possible and explains workarounds. The edit of the OP explains it though.

Comment: @night: That's exactly what the linked answer says...perhaps your question was "why can't I define multiple types in a declaration?", which isn't what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is wrong. You cannot declare variables of different *type* in the initialization part of `for`!

Do this:

```
int i = 1; 
for (vector<string>::iterator it = vecs.begin(); it != vecs.end(); ++it , i++) 
{
      cout << i << ". "<< *it << endl;
}
```

Or maybe, you would love just this:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ;  i < vecs.size(); ++i ) 
{
      cout << (i+1) << ". "<< vecs[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare variables of two different types in the "init" part of the for loop. Move the declaration of "i" (or of "it") to outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nice trick to not let your iterator out of scope:

```
void catchlabel()
{
    if(vecs.empty())
        return;
    else
    {
    cout << "The Sizeof the Vector is: " << vecs.size() << endl; 
    cout << "Currently Stored Labels: " << endl;
    /* Error 1 */
    {
    vector<string>::iterator it = vecs.begin()
    for ( int i = 1; it != vecs.end(); ++it , i++) 
             cout << i << ". "<< *it << endl;
            cout << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

And I would say that if you need to manipulate both elements and their indexes it is simpler to use indexes in 'for' loop, not iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to count the element specifically, you can just calculate the distance from `vecs.begin()` as you go along:

```
void catchlabel()
{
    if(!vecs.empty())
    {
        cout << "The Sizeof the Vector is: " << vecs.size() << endl; 
        cout << "Currently Stored Labels: " << endl;
        for (vector<string>::iterator it = vecs.begin(); it != vecs.end(); ++it)
            cout << (it - vecs.begin() + 1) << ". "<< *it << endl; 
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```