# Can I declare variables of different types in the initialization of a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope, initializer, variable-declaration

Why does this C++ code not compile under VS2010:

```
for ( int a = 0, short b = 0; a < 10; ++a, ++b ) {}
```

while this one does:

```
short b = 0;
for ( int a = 0; a < 10; ++a, ++b ) {}
```

Is the declaration of two variables of different types inside the for-loop initializer prohibited? If so, how can you work around it?

Comment: Looks like you say. Using the same type works: `for ( int a = 0, b = 0; a < 10; ++a, ++b ) {}` Hmm. Never noticed that before.

Comment: Yes this is the "double loop" mechanism that came from the C language. Quite rare, though. Not very readable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, that is prohibited. Just as otherwise you cannot declare variables of differing types in one declaration statement (*edit*: modulo the declarator modifiers that @MrLister mentions). You can declare structs

```
for (struct { int a = 0; short b = 0; } d; d.a < 10; ++d.a, ++d.b ) {}
```

C++03 code:

```
for (struct { int a; short b; } d = { 0, 0 }; d.a < 10; ++d.a, ++d.b ) {}
```

Of course when all are `0`, you can omit the initializers altogether and write `= { }`.

Comment: I hate the fact that you have shared this. I bet we will spend the next year answering silly variations on the usage of this. When in reality we never want to see it again.

Comment: @Loki: This wasn't exactly the first time the `for struct` hack appeared on SO.

Comment: @Fred http://stackoverflow.com/a/889001/34509

Comment: Not working with MSVC12. Workaround for 2 variable declarations: `for (auto i = std::make_pair(myVec1Iter.begin(), myVec2Iter.begin()); ... ; ...) {...}`

Answer (score 11):

Nothing to do with the `for` loop. This also doesn't compile if you write `int a = 0, short b = 0;` outside of any loop.
So the answer is: it is *always* forbidden to declare two variables of different types in a single statement.

Edit: Oh, for the pedantic, I do realise that you can declare a base type and a pointer type in the same statement, for instance an int and an int pointer, so those would be different types, yes.
Hm, that makes me think. In a 32 bit environment, a pointer would be 4 bytes, just like an int, so you could use short a = 0, *b = 0; and then cast b to an int. Hm...

Answer (score 1):

What is prohibited is the ending of a statement with a comma as you do in `int a = 0, short ...`

If you want to use this notation then bothe variable muss have the same type `int i = 0, s = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You can only declare one type in for statement. So the second code is the usable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable into the `while` condition of the `for` (the comprobation step).

```
for ( a = 0, short b = 0; a < 10; ++a, ++b ) {}
```

that's neither works.