# New ISO scoping rule for " for LOOP"

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a piece of code that was written by someone else before the New ISO come into effect.

The `for` LOOP in `for (pa=a.begin(), i=0; pa != a.end(); ++pa)` has a little trouble executing because of the `i=0` part of the syntax. Also, I had to prefix the other `for` loop syntaxes to read `for ( int i .....)`  with the `int` before the `i`. However, I don't know how to fix the `int i=0` in this line:  `for (pa=a.begin ( ), i=0; pa != a.end ( ); ++pa)`.  Please help me out.

```
  for ( int i = 0; pa != a.end(); ++pa)
      *pa = ++i;

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      std::cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] << std::endl;

  // int i;  // note that this will work, but I do not want this extra line.

  for (pa=a.begin(), i=0; pa != a.end(); ++pa)
      std::cout << "a[" << i++ << "]=" << *pa << std::endl;
```

Comment: It was written before the first standard was finished in 1997. And I doubt that just because you don't want that extra line, people will change the language to not require it...

Comment: You could use a `std::pair` or a struct, but that line is a lot easier to read.

Comment: Put that extra line, cringe a little and move on.

Comment: points well taken, but I was wondering if there is a more "compact" syntax, something to the effects of : for (pa=a.begin(), int i=0; .......), but the int i=0; declaration here won't work because of the comma preceding the "int". Any further clarification and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop?lq=1

Comment: Check this stack overflow link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop

Comment: That *New ISO* has something like 14 years. The *new new ISO* was approved last year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare variables of different types in the initialization of a for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644707/can-i-declare-variables-of-different-types-in-the-initialization-of-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extra declaration outside the `for` loop is the only sensible way to have two iteration variables of unrelated types in C++98 and later versions of the language. The initialiser can either be a single expression or a single declaration, and a declaration can't declare variables of multiple unrelated types.

If you really want a one-liner in this situation, then you could use this monstrosity:

```
for (int i = ((pa = a.begin()), 0); pa != a.end(); ++pa, ++i)
```

If you do that sort of thing regularly, then make sure that no-one who maintains your code knows where you live.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can declare only variables of one type inside the `for`. If your problem is scope then you may enclose the loop inside a block (for some nice examples look boost source code for loop macros):

```
for ( int i = 0; pa != a.end(); ++pa)
    *pa = ++i;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] << std::endl;

{
    int i = 0;
    for (pa=a.begin(); pa != a.end(); ++pa)
        std::cout << "a[" << i++ << "]=" << *pa << std::endl;
}
```

If you simply want to make it more nice then the answer is *no, you can't*.

**EDIT**
The **best trick** I saw to do what you need and to keep it clear is on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644707/can-i-declare-variables-of-different-types-in-the-initialization-of-a-for-loop?rq=1) on SO. Instead of multiple variables you can use an unnamed struct declared inline:

```
for (struct { int i; iterator it; } d = { 0, pa.begin() }; d.it != a.end(); ++d.i, ++d.it )
    std::cout << "a[" << d.i << "]=" << *d.it << std::endl;
```

It's a little bit more prolix (so I wonder if what you save with the extra line is re-payed) but you make clear your intent and you keep code readable (moreover you can use it to *pack* **any number and any type** of variables).

Comment: Thank you all for all the nice thought provocative answers !