# Why c++ does not support multiple initializers in for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, programming-languages, language-lawyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ why can't I write a for() loop like this: for( int i = 1, double i2 = 0;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337126/in-c-why-cant-i-write-a-for-loop-like-this-for-int-i-1-double-i2-0) 
>   [Why is it so 'hard' to write a for-loop in C++ with 2 loop variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440066/why-is-it-so-hard-to-write-a-for-loop-in-c-with-2-loop-variables)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0, double j = 3.0; i < 10; i++, j+=0.1)
        cout << i << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

does not compile, becuase there are two declaration in the for-loop initializer block.

But Why?

Comment: Such is the syntax of the language :) There's nothing technical that prevented the designers of the language from slipping in the syntax that you expect, but for one reason or the other they just didn't :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C++ grammar, **different data types are separated with `;`** (if not function). In `for` loop, once the `;` is found the meaning is changed. i.e.

```
for (<initializations>; <condition>; <next operation>)
```

Other reason is possibly to avoid complexity in an already complex grammar, this feature is not allowed.

If you want to declare variables in `for` loop scope, then you can always simulate that situation:

```
int main()
{
  {
    double j = 3.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, j+=0.1)
        cout << i << j << endl;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 53):

If you want `int` and `double` both, in the initialization, then one way to do this is to define an anonymous struct! Yes, you **can** define `struct` in the `for` loop, as well. It seems to be a *less known* feature of C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for( struct {int i; double j;} v = {0, 3.0}; v.i < 10; v.i++, v.j+=0.1)
       std::cout << v.i << "," << v.j << std::endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
0,3
1,3.1
2,3.2
3,3.3
4,3.4
5,3.5
6,3.6
7,3.7
8,3.8
9,3.9
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/6hvmq

Comment: +1 for beautiful solution, never thought of this. But I think, anonymous `struct` are g++ extension. Is this way allowed in all compilers?

Comment: @iammilind: It is not g++ extension. It is Standard C++.

Comment: I'm confused by your second sentence. Was there ever doubt that we can define structs? Doesn't seem like something that needs special affirmation. What does "as well" refer too?

Comment: @RobKennedy: I said that because it is a feature which is not known to most C++ programmers.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Sort of agree. But then, it is much more readable than `typedef typename X::template Y<T>::type my_type`. :D

Answer (score 12):

Because the syntax was already taken. In a variable declaration/definition, separating with commas adds new variables of the same type, not of different types. That syntax is available in `for` loops:

```
for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end();
      it != end; ++it ) {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: If someone writes, `int i, d;` then it's understood that variables must be of same type (inside or outside the loop). But, I think asker is arguing that why `int i, double d;` is not allowed by C++ grammar, by adding some more complexity.

Comment: @iammilind: the first block of the for loop is a variable declaration. In that context, the comma already has a meaning and exact semantics that are consistent with all other variable declarations. Of course you can special case all constructs, call this a *for-loop-declaration-list* and completely redefine the same concepts available for a declaration. The result would be a more complex set of rules in which to support his (arguably less frequent use case) I would have to retype the already complex type of the iterator for no extra real value (it does not enable any new construct

Comment: ... there are simple workarounds if you need multiple variables of different types defined. For starters, as you proposed, you can enclose the loop in a scope and declare all other variables in that scope. You can also avoid the extra scope by using composite types, like `std::pair`: `for ( pair<int,double> p( 0, 0.0 ); p.first < 10; ++p.first, p.second+=0.1 )`... or tuples for multiple such variables.