# Commas in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, comma-operator

Why is the following line producing errors?

```
for(int i = 0, int pos = 0, int next_pos = 0; i < 3; i++, pos = next_pos + 1) {
  // …
}

error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
error: ‘pos’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘next_pos’ was not declared in this scope
```

Compiler is g++.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337126/in-c-why-cant-i-write-a-for-loop-like-this-for-int-i-1-double-i2-0 which seems to reference an earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340073/multiple-counter-problem-in-for-loop which appears to be  pretty good duplicate for *this* question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have only one type of declaration per statement, so you only need one int:

```
for(int i = 0, pos = 0, next_pos = 0; i < 3; i++, pos = next_pos + 1)
```

Comment: And it's disappointing that there's no means to make some of the declarations `const` and some of them not.

Comment: @seh: `for ( struct { int anything; const int you; float want;} data = {5, 10, 3.14f}; ...; ...)`

Comment: @seh @strager: :) I agree it's a bit ugly, I probably wouldn't do it in real code (haven't so far), but it is a way. Far easier just to define the variables above the loop.

Answer (score 4):

In a normal program:

```
int main()
{

int a=0,int b=0,int c=0;
return 0;    

}
```

will never work and is not accepted.

This is what you are actually trying to do inside the for loop!