# For loop for variable - value initialization

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was inspired by answer of @fredoverflow from this question : [Multiple Counter Problem In For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340073/multiple-counter-problem-in-for-loop)

So I have bunch of variables and bunch of values for them, that I would to pass throw functions. For example:

```
 bool a, b, c;
 string string_a, string_b, string_c;
 a = foo(string_a);
 b = foo(string_b);
 c = foo(string_c);
```

Instead of writing this all manually, can I create for loop in a way like this:

```
for (struct {bool boo; string str;} loop: {{a, string_a}, {b, string_b}, {c, string_c}}){
    loop.boo = foo(loop.str);
}
```

It does not looks like legit way for variable assignment, or I missed a couple of symbols here?
And is such tricks considered a good practice?

Comment: Good practice is writing clear and readable code. And you might have scope issues.

Comment: Just assign the booleans, one by one, at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) may be helpful.

```
std::vector<string> src = {string_a, string_b, string_c};
std::vector<bool> dest(src.size());

std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dest.begin(), foo);
```

To have it modify the variables, you can do like this with [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool*, string*> > targets = {{&a, &string_a}, {&b, &string_b}, {&c, &string_c}};
std::for_each(targets.begin(), targets.end(), [](auto& p){ *p.first = foo(*p.second); });
```

or with `for` statement:

```
for(auto loop: std::vector<std::pair<bool*, string*> > {{&a, &string_a}, {&b, &string_b}, {&c, &string_c}}) {
    *loop.first = foo(*loop.second);
}
```

Comment: Are you writing this in the pub?

Answer (score 0):

#### Combining structured bindings with range based for loops with (C++20) initialization statements

As of C++20, you can use [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) initialization statements, which you can combine with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) as follows:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

bool foo(std::string_view s) {
    return s == "b";  
}

int main() {
    bool a{false}, b{false}, c{false};
    std::string string_a{"a"}, string_b{"b"}, string_c{"c"};
    
    for (typedef std::pair<bool&, std::string_view> P;
         auto [res, str] : {P{a, string_a}, {b, string_b}, {c, string_c}}) {
        res = foo(str);
    }
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";
        // false true false
}
```

leveraging the fact that [`typedef` declarations are *init-statements*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196340/4573247) (where *alias-declarations* are not) to declare the `P` utility alias, which is in turn used to type deduction in the initializer list over which the range based for loop iterates (and binds values).

Prior to C++20, you could simply place the utility type alias before the loop:

```
using P = std::pair<bool&, std::string_view>;
for (auto [res, str] : {P{a, string_a}, {b, string_b}, {c, string_c}}) {
    res = foo(str);
}
```

or remove the utility type alias entirely:

```
for (auto [res, str] : {
        std::pair<bool&, std::string_view>{a, string_a},
        {b, string_b}, {c, string_c}}) {
    res = foo(str);
}
```

---

> And is such tricks considered a good practice?

This part of the answer may go into the opinion based domain, and whilst this not not necessarily apply to the snippet above, it surely does so to technique used [in the answer you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2341451/4573247) (*"Hackety hack hack"*). Syntactic compositions are so clever they end up being referred to as *"tricks"* may end up being be too clever for their own good, and inhibit clarity and understanding of the code base, for the writer of the particular code as well as for other (current and future) maintainers.